# How can I add a column to a dataframe in Spark, whose values will depend on the contents of a 2nd dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Say I have one dataframe, df1, one of it's columns is "city."

I need to create a new column, which will basically list how many the times the particular city name occurs in a second dataframe, df2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var df3 =df2.groupBy("city").count

df1.join(df3,Seq("city"), "left")
```

That will provide you the answer. Here join is used as a lookup technique